# How to Align three images side by side using report lab

Tags: reportlab

I am generating the pdf but i want the images to be displayed side by side.(horizontally) using report lab and the text also to be displayed at the bottom of each and every image
By using Image function with horizontal align = left and center i have used.
one image is displaying on the left corner and other image is displaying in the center corner but not in the same line

Answer (score 3):

One option may be using Table to align your images. I have used this technique with graphs drawn in Reportlab, it may work for images as well.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

# assuming image1, image2, image3 are your images. change colWidths and rowHeights 
# as needed

catalog = []
chart_style = TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                          ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER')])

catalog.append(Table([[image1, image2, image3]],
                     colWidths=[3.3 * inch, 3.3 * inch, 3.3 * inch],
                     rowHeights=[2.5 * inch], style=chart_style))
```

Comment: do you have an idea to display caption below each image